# Oscilloscope range affecting voltage reading

Tags: current-measurement, oscilloscope, voltage-measurement

I am trying to measure the current usage of a device using an oscilloscope. 
Every second the device turns on for a few milliseconds and then goes back to sleep. I need to find how much current is being used both when it is sleeping and when it is awake. I set up this circuit to help me read the current as a voltage across R1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFVrTH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have found that the voltage range setting on my scope seems to affect the readings a lot.

Voltage Range ==> Reading

200mV ==> 1.76V

500mV ==> 4.39V

1V =====> 5.02V

2V =====> 5.24V

I can't see the sleep current without the 200mV range and I don't know which reading I should use for my calculations. Why am I seeing varying voltages and how can I fix my circuit?

Edit: Here is a picture of the waveform in question. this one is scaled to 500mV/Div because you can't see the top at 200mV/Div.
[image]

Comment: It strikes me as suspicious that your 1st 2 measurements are both 8.8 divisions (1.76/0.2 = 8.8,  4.39/0.5 = 8.78). Where exactly do you get those voltage readings from?

Comment: Michael, I think you mean V/div not range. Yet scope impedance is what 1M? across 330R  ? is it in calibrated?

Comment: Can you show please the waveforms?

Comment: In any case, if you're measuring several volts across the shunt, you're not applying the voltage  to the device you intended. You can use the change of voltage across a capacitor for measurements like this if you're looking at the amount of energy used in short bursts. Or do you need to actually know the current?

Comment: The range doesn't affect the readings if the scope is good. Is it a real scope, or something like an audio card + scope software?

Comment: The combined resistance across R1 is 328.9 Ohms @SunnyskyguyEE75

Comment: The device has a regulator on it. I should still be within it's operating range. If my reading is a little higher than it actually is would be fine.@PhilG

Comment: What kind of probe do you have on that scope? And what is the gain on it set to? Have you tried testing the probe with the square wave generator on the front of the scope?

Comment: If the trace exceeds display , it may be clipped but the resolution in V/div should never change the result. So what's wrong? Your test method or the DSO?

Comment: https://uk.tek.com/datasheet/passive-10x-voltage-probe @laptop2d

Comment: You cannot read 1.76V on a 200mV scale of 8 divisions.  The most would be 1.6V.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat You can with a cursor (the one that gave out the answer :) )

Comment: Your comment intrigued me and I did some digging on the subject. I didn't know that the scope would clip readings on lower ranges. This looks like it was the problem. Thanks.@SunnyskyguyEE75

Comment: I thought everyone knew that ;)

Comment: haha I am still a little new to this stuff.@SunnyskyguyEE75

Comment: I don't suppose you can post the clipping response as an answer so I can accept it and give you credit for the find. I would like to close the question as to not waste anyone else's time.@SunnyskyguyEE75

Answer (score 2):

```
Range      Reading
200 mV ==> 1.76 V
500 mV ==> 4.39 V
```

I can't see that second reading on your trace.

[image]

*Figure 1. On the 500 mV/div range you are reading > 3 x 500 mV and the (b) reading is 1.76 V, the same as your 200 mV/div range reading.*

I don't think the scope is at fault.

Comment: That was going to be my comment.

Comment: Mine too. I think there is some confusion between "voltage range" and "voltage per division" on OP side...

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 If it was 1x, reading at 200mV would be the same as 500mV, etc.  I don't think the scope is at fault.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was my ignorance on how the oscilloscope works. I had assumed that if I took a reading on the 200mV/Div range it would show up when zoomed out even if the reading was something high like 10V. I did not know that the higher voltages get clipped on the low scale. Thanks to Sunnyskyguy EE75 for sparking the question that led me to the solution, and thank you all for your quick responses.

Comment: learn all the best methods of test measurement